# Create a loop that import bas files in every .xlsm files from a folder?

Tags: excel, vba

The actual code :

```
Sub throwaway()
    Dim xStrPath As String
    Dim xFileDialog As FileDialog
    Dim xFile As String
    Dim strFolder As String: strFolder = "K:\blabla" & "\"
    Dim strTempFile As String: strTempFile = strFolder & "aaOWB.bas"
    
    
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a folder"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    xFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xlsm")
    
    Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents("aaOWB").Export strTempFile
    
    Do While xFile <> ""
        Workbooks.Open xStrPath & "\" & xFile
        Application.VBE.VBProject(xStrPath & "\" & xFile).Unprotect Password:=700
        Application.VBE.VBProject(xStrPath & "\" & xFile).VBComponents.Import strTempFile
        Application.VBE.VBProject(xStrPath & "\" & xFile).Protect Password:=700
        Application.VBE.VBProject(xStrPath & "\" & xFile).Close (SaveChanges)
        xFile = Dir
    Loop
    
End Sub
```

This code actually open the file dialog, but after I select the right files it doesn't show anything…

My computer is not really a beast, but maybe if I open each files and import one by one in the loop it could work?(just scared to crash)

Comment: I am pretty sure that you have to open the xlsm-file first before importing the bas module

Comment: 1- You can export the file out of the loop, since it's the same all the time. You might want to delete the exported file after the loop, to not leave outdated files on the system.
2- Don't use `On error Resume Next` excepted in very limited places, it will hide errors that should be solved.
3- objExcel is undefined in the posted context, you can probably use Application here BTW
4- [VBProjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/visual-basic-add-in-model/collections-visual-basic-add-in-model#vbprojects) (plural) only contains currently opened projects

Comment: 1. You must open each such workbook. 2. What do you want doing by previously exporting the module? You should remove it, **if exists**. Or if you need to keep it for I do not know what reason, choose a different folder where to export it. 3. Using the full path for setting a `VBProject` is wrong. You should use the workbook name. 4. Comment `On Error Resume Next`! This will only not let you see the errors raised when try fancy things...

Comment: @VincentG 4- You mean when i use VBProject it only looks for opened workbooks so i need to open them before right ?

Comment: @FaneDuru 3- But the file where my bas file come from is on my computer and I want to export my bas file into workbooks that be on my server… Wouldn't be a problem, you think?

Comment: I made an edit taking each of your suggestions but i got error 438 there ```Application.VBE.VBProject(xStrPath & "\" & xFile).Unprotect Password:=700```

Comment: "import bas files in every .xlsm files from a folder" meant for me that **the bass file(s) is/are already in the respective folder**... If not, you did not well explain **in words** what you try doing. So, do you want exporting a module (named "aaOWB") and then import it in the workbooks from "xStrPath"? I can see now a different code than in the moment I answered. I mean only once (correct) exporting it and then trying to import and saving. I told you in my comment that `VBProject(xStrPath & "\" & xFile)` does not make any sense.

Comment: What you try doing by `Application.VBE.VBProject(xStrPath & "\" & xFile).Unprotect Password:=700`? What protection do you try removing? A `VBProject` object does not have such a property! Anyhow, you should set a workbook `VBProject` as `Workbooks(xFile).VbProject`. And using as `Workbooks(xFile).VbProject.VBComponents.Import strTempFile`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248557/discussion-between-salifgotem-and-faneduru).